# QByteArray convert to hex fails

Tags: c++, qt, gmp

I am using GMP in a QT project, and I am trying to use QByteArray to store some of the numbers.

When I want to convert a byte array to an mpz_t I am doing the following:

```
const char *hexstring = qbyteval.toHex().toStdString().c_str();
mpz_t myval;
mpz_init (myval);
mpz_set_str(myval, hexstring, 16);

mpz_t zero;
mpz_init(zero);
mpz_set_str(zero, "0", 10);

if(mpz_comp(myval, zero) == 0) {
//...set a breakpoint or do something here. This line shouldn't be reached ever.
}
```

In my case, `qbyteval` is never zero. If I set a breakpoint inside that mpz_comp if block, qbyteval.toHex() is always still a hex string.

What is failing, that is causing hexstring to be an empty string (and thus myval =0)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
const char *hexstring = qbyteval.toHex().toStdString().c_str();
```

The `c_str()` function returns a pointer to the internal data in a `std::string`, and that pointer can become invalidated if you modify or destroy the `std::string`.  In this case, the `std::string` gets destroyed right after that line runs, because you didn't store it in a variable.

There might be more errors like this in your code, but that is the most glaring error.  If you still have trouble, I suggest posting a minimal, complete example and better explaining the expected behavior vs the actual behavior, and using a debugger to look at what is happening on every line.

Comment: I am sorry David. Now I understood what you guys are talking about.... I misunderstood that you are talking about "data()" function.... But Now I am clear what mistake I did by assigning it to "const Char*"... The main reason I messed up with it is, I was using a variable for testing here.... That variable is  a RWCString declared in some headers...... Now I have a question? ....How a rougewave string is able to hold it? I mean "RWCString str = qstr.toLatin1().data()".....is doing good. If you want me to post it as a question I will do that.

Comment: The toLatin1() again returns a QByteArray. Sorry for communication gap again.... totally messed up and wasted your time..

Comment: RWCString, if it's like std::string, probably has a constructor that copies all the data out of the char pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `const char*` out of the byte array, you must ensure that the buffer isn't a temporary and outlives any and all uses of the pointer:

```
void function(const QByteArray & byteVal) {
  auto const hex = byteVal.toHex();
  mpz_t myval;
  mpz_init (myval);
  mpz_set_str(myval, hex.data(), 16);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me. I didn't initialize myval.

```
mpz_t myval;
mpz_set_str(myval.backend().data(), hexstring, 16);
```